# C# tabbed MDI forms: Always last tab is closed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabs, mdi

I was following the tabbed MDI forms example from [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17640/Tabbed-MDI-Child-Forms). I just copied the code into a test application.

The problem is, that if I press the "X" button to close a form, always the last tab closes and not the selected one.
But in the example solution it works perfectly. However I can't find any difference in code, properties or events to my test project.

I hope someone gives me a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  private void tabForms_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

you may missed this code of , forgot the event binding with this

Comment: Thank you... I was sure I checked every event, but I missed that.